# Pythonic way to alter keyboard key characters

Tags: python, keyboard

I want to build google inputs like offline app with python.

I want detect keyboard key press with python and alter the key pressed value to some other values and insert the altered character to screen. (input field (Notepad)).

How do insert value to input field with python like a virtual keyboard inputs?

Example:

If i pressed a -> m will be shown in input field (Notepad or ..)
likewise b -> d ,c -> g, e -> u, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, I find the simplest is to just detect user input, and press backspace after each key is pressed. You'll need `pyautogui` and `keyboard` to do this.

Something like this:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui

keys = {'a': 'm', 'b': 'd'} #only added a few keys, could add many more

while True: #while loop, will always detect keys forever
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    pyautogui.press('Backspace') #presses backspace so no user input
    virtual_key = keys[key] #key to be virtually pressed
    pyautogui.press(virtual_key) #virtually press the key
```

This is just a simple code example that will press whatever key is desired. I only added 2 keys into the dictionary `keys`, but you could add more if needed.